# How to test if a set contains object with id in js

Tags: javascript, typescript, set

I want to create this function:

```
const hasObject = (myObjectSet: Set<MyObject>) => {
  if (myObjectSet.size === 0) {
    return false
  }
    
  // test if there is an object with id 4
}
```

The equivalent of `some` for an array.

***EDIT***

I made it like this at the end:

```
const hasObject = (myObjectSet: Set<MyObject>) => {
  if (myObjectSet.size === 0) {
    return false
  }
    
  let result = false

  myObjectSet.forEach((myObject) => {
    if(myObject.id === 4) {
      result = true
    }
  }) 

  return result
}
```

Comment: What's a `Line`? If this is a TypeScript question it would help if you provide a [mre] that can be dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w8K6AW) and demonstrate your issue without errors unrelated to your question.

Comment: `Line` is just an object with an `id`. This is not important here. This is not a `Typescript` question. `Set` is in `JS` too

Comment: JS arrays have a `some` function - maybe `Set` has as well?

Comment: If it's not important then it would help you to change the example code so that nobody has to think about it.  I can do that myself, but it takes some modicum of effort that ideally comes from the person asking and not those offering help.  Anyway, assuming `Line` is equivalent to `{id: number}`, the only way to do this is iterate the set until you find a matching element, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NlxMxN) maybe.  If that meets your needs I could write up an answer assuming I don't find a duplicate question first.

Comment: @AdriHM "This is not a `Typescript` question." Ah, see, I follow the "typescript" tag, so it looks like one from where I sit.  Feel free to untag it and ideally remove the type annotations.

Comment: I thought we could do bettter than a conversion in array, that's why I made a post but ok thx everybody

Comment: If you notice, [this](https://tsplay.dev/NlxMxN) does not convert to an array; it iterates the set using its `values()` iterator.  There is no built-in `some()` but you could write one if you really needed to.

Comment: I made it with the `forEach` method of the `Set`

Comment: I think it's better to reopened the post to put the answer with the `forEach` no ?

Comment: The version with `forEach()` keeps iterating after it finds the element, right? In any case if you think it's a good answer you might want to add it to one of the other linked questions.